# PATCH_SUPEE-6788, 1.7.02 Issue - Part 2

Tags: magento-1.7, patches

Facing the same problem as the user here ([Why does PATCH_SUPEE-6788 appear to have no effect on a 1.7.0.2 installation?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87900/why-does-patch-supee-6788-appear-to-have-no-effect-on-a-1-7-0-2-installation)) -- I followed the suggested steps - downloaded a clean local copy of 1.7.02 off the Magento archive, and replaced the .htaccess and .htaccess.sample files on the server with the clean ones from the download. But when I go to execute the .sh file, I'm still getting an error --

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully... ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

 Hunk #1 FAILED at 131.
```

Any thoughts as to what may still be the problem?

Comment: Can you add full error message, it should notify which file is having trouble.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED SOLUTION:

It's likely that you've missed a patch. Go to https://www.magereport.com/scan and install past patches to make sure you're up to date, then try the latest 6788 patch again. This worked for me :)

---

just thought I'd add that I'm having the same problem. I found a solution that made sense: re-download an original 1.7.0.2 Magento install, and overwrite the conflicting file. For me I had 2 conflicts, one in my .htaccess (which I resolved using this solution), but the second file is still failing the "hunk" even after I've replaced it with the original.

```
Hunk #1 FAILED at 131.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php.rej
```

I'm going to keep working on this and I'll update if I find a solution.

Comment: The Magento patches are just plain `diff` files wrapped around by some script. You can try to apply them manually by the `patch` tool and resolve conflicting line by yourself.