# SUPEE-6788 Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-6788

I'm trying to patch my local Magento website for the SUPEE 6788 patch but I'm receiving some errors when running the .sh file via Git Bash:

```
NETWORK+Liam.McArthur@NETWORK MINGW32 /c/xampp/htdocs/magento
$ sh PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.1.0_v1-2015-10-27-09-06-11.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file .htaccess
Hunk #1 FAILED at 207.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file .htaccess.sample
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block/Collection.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable/Collection.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Variable.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.1-1.6.1.2.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit/Form.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Grid.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit/Form.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Grid.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/BlockController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/VariableController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/adminhtml.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/File.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 291 (offset -7 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/UnserializeArray.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Changeforgotten.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Resetpassword.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Product/Type.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Resource/Attribute/Collection.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Item/Collection.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/DownloadController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Resource/Coupon/Collection.php
checking file app/code/core/Zend/XmlRpc/Request.php
checking file app/code/core/Zend/XmlRpc/Response.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/admin.xml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/js/cookie.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/layout/customer.xml
checking file app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/customer.xml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/customer.xml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
checking file cron.php
checking file errors/processor.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrKey.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Bool.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Dbl.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Int.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Str.php
checking file lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php
checking file lib/Zend/Xml/Security.php
```

Is this line 207 of my .htaccess file is failing?

Comment: For the record mine complained about the exact same number 207. Not sure if it is a line number issue as in my .htaccess file that line is commented out.

Comment: Replace the .htaccess and the .htaccess.sample with the original from the Magento download. This fixed the problem for me (like the below answer shows) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the solution posted on [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/87903/3744).  The patch is sensitive to changes in `.htaccess` files, and also requires all previous security patches to have been applied.