# Patch can't be applied SUPPE-10266 CE

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

When I try to apply the patch on my Magento application this is what I get:

```
[http]$ bash PATCH_SUPEE-10266_CE_1.9.2.4_v1.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Grid/Renderer/Notice.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Newsletter/QueueController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Newsletter/TemplateController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Helper/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Item/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Serializer/Adapter/PhpCode.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/backup/dialogs.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/options/type/file.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/view.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 70.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/view.phtml.rej
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/login.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/toolbar.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/oauth/authorize/form/login-simple.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/oauth/authorize/form/login.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/history.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
patching file app/design/install/default/default/template/install/create_admin.phtml
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
patching file downloader/template/login.phtml
```

Anyone know what could be the cause of patch not applying in full and how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution posted on this answer. The patch is sensitive to changes in .htaccess files, and also requires all previous security patches to have been applied.

[SUPEE-6788 Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88057/supee-6788-patch-cant-be-applied-reverted-successfully)