# SUPEE-9767 : Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-9767

I'm trying to Install SUPEE-9767 but i get this error message:

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Checkout/Formkey.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Symlink.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/Date.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Adapter/Zend/Cache.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Container/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Xml/Excel.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Uploader.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Model/Widget/Instance.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Helper/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/formkey.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/symlink.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 109 with fuzz 2.
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 91 with fuzz 2.
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 126 with fuzz 2.
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
```

How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: refer to this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/87903/55030 hope it helps you.

Comment: I don't see any failures in this error message - usually the "Patch can't be applied" error is followed by at least one "Hunk #XX failed at XXX" error. Can you paste any missing lines for completeness?

Comment: Facing similar issue nothing failed but its still showing Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

Comment: shall i know it is work?. if work please accept the ans :)

Answer (score 1):

`Hunk #1 succeeded at 109 with fuzz 2`.

The message you see means the file was successfully patched, fuzz 2 means  Some lines had only spaces but they got trimmed to empty lines, so the patch file applied correctly, but with fuzz factors warnings display.

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
```

**Note:** In SUPEE-9767 the above three files are `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml(“formkey”) ?>` was added. if your overwrite the file in your theme please add foormkey in your theme.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187706/patch-9767-cant-be-applied-reverted-successfully-in-magento-1-9-3-1/187709?noredirect=1#comment259947_187709