# Patch 9767 can't be applied/reverted successfully in Magento 1.9.3.1

Tags: magento-1.9, error, patches, supee-9767

I installed few patches in Magento 1.9.3.1. I tried to installed Patch SUPEE-9767 v2 from sh and manually as well. I am getting "patch can't be applied/reverted successfully" as error message. I have described all error messages in following image . Could anyone give possible solution for it?

[image]

I didn't find any answer from same Questions so i put this question for magento 1.9.3.1
Thank You

Comment: Yes but i didn't get answer from it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly apply patch by overwriting files in zip.

You can find it here https://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-9767-without-ssh/

According to your version, choose file.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this link.  I am trying this. @Kishan Patadia

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped you.